# JQGrid filterToolbar

Tags: jqgrid

I have been stuck on this problem for past 2 days. Did lot of googling but was not able to find the exact answer.

Following is the JQGrid definition

```
$("#tblresults").jqGrid({
            datastr: data,
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            height: 230,
            colNames: colNames,
            colModel: colModel,
            rowNum: -1,
            viewrecords: true,
            loadComplete: function() {
                ChangeSize('#tblresults', 70);
            }
        });
```

And this is the filter definition

```
    $("#tblresults").filterToolbar({ searchOnEnter: true, stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn", groupOp: "AND" });
```

I get the data from a simple getJSON call. But when I try to use the filter nothing works.
I debugged a the code and found out that jqgrid internally calls the reloadgrid, which makes the data to disappear.

Can anyone tell me how can we do filtering in jqgrid completely on client. 
I am using v3.8 and I learnt that jqgrid v3.7 had this client side filtering logic in place.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the data First of all you should not use -1 as the value of `rowNum`. Instead of that use any reliable value like `rowNum:1000`. More better would be to use local data paging. In the case you should just set for example `rowNum:10, rowList:[5,10,20,100]`.

If you get the input parameters `colNames`, `colModel` and `data` parameters of jqGrid from the server per ajax call you should additionally consider to use `data` parameter instead of `datastr`. In the case the `datatype` should be changed from `'jsonstring'` to `'local'`.

Some other common parameters like `gridview:true` and `height:'100%'` can be also usefull for you. The first one (`gridview:true`) just improve the performance without any disadvantages and the second (`height:'100%'`) will follow to choosing of the optimal grid height without the vertical scroll bar. It can be good combined with the local data paging (parameters like `rowNum:10, rowList:[5,10,20,100]`).

Comment: I read somewhere that rowNum=-1 will show all records in the grid and that is my requirement. Record count would not go over 200 in any case so vertical scroll bar is fine. I would try changing the datatype and data parameters and see if it works. But for now I have used the old approach of filtering the records on the server.

Comment: @Nilesh: The value `rowNum=-1` could be OK if you send the value to the server. The value was used old in versions of jqGrid (<3.7), About the value 200 as the number of rows. Is it really needed to fill the part of browser window before the user scroll the window? If you will use `rowNum:10` instead of `rowNum:200` the grid will be 20 time quickly ready. Are the user able to read and **analyse** the 200 rows of grid? Probably sorting and filtering (see [toolbar filtering](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) will be better for the user and one can use paging.

Answer (score 0):

add these parameters and your toolbar search should work. i have faced similar problem too when started with jqgrid.

```
search:true,
loadonce:true,
```